# simple_form turn boolean into dropdown with labels

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have a boolean column in my model. Say it's called isType1.

Now in my form, I would like to have a dropdown with two values (type1 if boolean is true, and type2 if boolean is false) instead of a checkbox or radio buttons.

Is that possible?

Right now I am displaying it as radio buttons:

```
<%= f.input :isType,  :as => :radio, :label => "Type"%>
```

I would prefer if I had a dropdown where the user could select type1 or type2 without changing the model to a string instead of a boolean.

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is what I was looking for:

```
<%= f.input :isType, 
            :as => :select, 
            :collection => [['Type1',false],['Type2',true]], 
            :include_blank => false, 
            :label => "Type" %>
```

Comment: Be assured that the `true` & `false` values are passed as `strings` and not `booleans`. So If in controller you are checking for the true false values it won't work.

Comment: How about :collection => [['No',0],['Yes',1]] ?

Answer (score 1):

Just use select for this:

`<%= f.input :isType, :as => :select, :label => "Type"%>`

Comment: yea but actually in the dropdown I do not want "yes" and "no" as values but my own labels for example "type1", "type2". For example if the boolean value of :istype is true then the label for that option is "type1"

Comment: This is what I was looking for  <%= f.input :isType, :as => :select, :collection => [['Type1',false],['Type2',true]], :include_blank => false, :label => "Type"%>

Comment: I see. You can post as an answer though :)

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `include_blank: false`, You must add `disabled: []` to allow the falsy values to not be disabled within the select.

```
<%= f.input :isType, 
            as: :select, 
            collection: [['Type1',false],['Type2',true]], 
            include_blank: false, 
            disabled: [] %>
```